# XSLT Select multiple attribute with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt

Good morning, I am new to XLS and I trying to display a XML containing 'Menu' items . But each dish contain many ingredient tags , and I can't manage to display them in a list in my table .
This is my XML:

```
<Menu>
    <dish Id='001'>
        <general_info>
            <name>Margharita</name>
            <description>Mozzarela slices, tomatoes, basil and extra olive oil</description>
            <type>Pizza</type>
        </general_info>

        <nutrition_info>
            <ingredient>Mozzarela</ingredient>
            <ingredient>tomatoes</ingredient>
            <ingredient>basil</ingredient>
            <ingredient>olive oil</ingredient>
            <ingredient>flour</ingredient>
            <dietary_restrictions>Allergic to Gluten</dietary_restrictions>
        </nutrition_info>

        <price>RS300</price>
    </dish>

    <dish Id='002'>
        <general_info>
            <name>Chicken Burger</name>
            <description>Chicken regular Hamburger</description>
            <type>Burger</type>
        </general_info>

        <nutrition_info>
            <ingredient>bread</ingredient>
            <ingredient>chicken</ingredient>
            <ingredient>tomato</ingredient>
            <ingredient>cheddar</ingredient>
            <ingredient>onions</ingredient>
            <ingredient>lettuce</ingredient>
            <dietary_restrictions></dietary_restrictions>
        </nutrition_info>

        <price>RS290</price>
    </dish>
</Menu>
```

And this is my XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h2><center>Menu</center></h2>
          <table border="1">
              <tr bgcolor="orange">
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Type</th>
                  <th>Ingredients</th>
                  <th>dietary restrictions</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
              </tr>

              <xsl:for-each select="Menu/dish">
              <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="general_info/name"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="general_info/description"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="general_info/type"/></td>
                  <td>
                    <ul>
                      <xsl:for-each select="Menu/dish/nutrition_info">
                      <li><xsl:value-of select="ingredient"/></li>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </ul>
                  </td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="nutrition_info/dietary_restrictions"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
              </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And i'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
Name      | Description | TYPE | Ingredients | dietary restrictions | Price
Margharita|.............|Pizza |list of items|......................|......
etc
```

Note that each dish may have a different number of ingredient attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use relative path

```
<ul>
  <xsl:for-each select="nutrition_info">
    <xsl:for-each select="ingredient">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not working with templates instead of for-each?

Comment: imho it's easier to understand for non xslt experts... using templates will also work

Comment: Yes, I quite agree with you! As starter I had there a problem too.

Comment: Thank you very much ! it work well. But can you possibly print the list on the same line? separated by comas by exemple?

Comment: use string-join: `<xsl:for-each select="nutrition_info">
  <xsl:value-of select="string-join( (ingredient), ',')" />
</xsl:for-each>`

Answer (score 0):

An example on how to use apply templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  >

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>
          <center>Menu</center>
        </h2>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Ingredients</th>
              <th>dietary restrictions</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Menu/dish"/>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="dish">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="general_info/name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="general_info/description"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="general_info/type"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="nutrition_info"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="nutrition_info/dietary_restrictions"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="nutrition_info">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ingredient"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ingredient">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```